# Solr 6.2.0 facet query response returning spitted results

Tags: solr, dih

I have created new core and indexed catalog from oracle DB using DIH. Indexing is successful. So now i am trying to query that using facet query as follows.

This is my data structure is been indexed.

```
{
        "sku_display_name":"Men's Brooks Adrenaline GTS-rojo -7.5",
        "id":"sku10017",
        "product_id":"prod10004",
        "product_display_name":"pre-Prod_MEN'S Brooks Adrenaline GTS ",
        "category_id":"cat10016",
        "category_display_name":"preCat_Casual Shoes",
        "_version_":1592465895497662464
},
      {
        "sku_display_name":"MUJERES ADIDAS BOOST ULTRA NUEVO - marron-10",
        "id":"sku10016",
        "product_id":"prod10003",
        "product_display_name":"pre-Prod_MUJERES ADIDAS BOOST ULTRA NUEVO",
        "category_id":"cat10019",
        "category_display_name":"preCat_Casual Tennis",
        "_version_":1592465895517585408
}
```

So my query is . `localhost:8983/solr/TestCore/select?facet.field=category_display_name&facet.query=true&facet=on&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json`

My issue is facets response the facets values. The below one is my response.

```
"facet_counts": {
      "facet_queries": {
         "true": 0
      },
      "facet_fields": {
         "category_display_name": [
            "shoes", -- But my actual facet value is *preCat_Casual Shoes*
            22,
            "precat_casual", -- But my actual facet value is *preCat_Casual 
            Shoes*
            15,
            "tennis",        -- preCat_Casual Tennis
            9,
         ]
      },
      "facet_ranges": {},
      "facet_intervals": {},
      "facet_heatmaps": {}
   }
```

Can you help me out from this? As per this behaviour it is splitting if the facet value has space.

Comment: Can you tell as what is the type `category_display_name` ? is that `string` or a `text` ?

Comment: It is type of text_ar

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is a splitting on space char, so to fix that you have to change your type (seems to be `text` with `WordDelimiterFilterFactory`) configuration to prevent Solr splitting on Space. To do that, go to your `\solr\schema.xml` and edit you type by removing this filtre `<filter .... class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" ..>`.

The second one, is a lowerCase transformation of results, to fix that i suggest to remove the folowing filter to :  `<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />`.

And if you use `text_ar`, you need to change it to `text_en` not `string`, `string` almost reserved for codes or IDs, because it matches the same word !

Comment: I don't have WordDelimiterFilterFactory in my definition also the second case also is not working however removing LowerCaseFilterFactory. 
Please let me know your concerns. 
 <fieldType name="text_ar"class="solr.TextField"positionIncrementGap="100"><analyzer type="index"><tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/><filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_ar.txt" ignoreCase="true"/><filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/> </analyzer>
</fieldType>

Comment: That is a strenge behavior, but why using `Arabic` configuration for field with `Latin` chars ? can you share with as the `<fieldType name="text" ...>` configuration ?

Comment: This configuration came from solr package.

Comment: <field name="category_display_name" type="text_ar" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="category_id" type="text_ar" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

Comment: Thank you nomade.. I have fixed by changing type from text_ar to string.
<field name="category_display_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="category_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="product_display_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="product_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="sku_description" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="sku_display_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
Thanks..

Comment: So, you need to change  `<field name="category_display_name" type="text_ar" ... ` to `<field name="category_display_name" type="text_en" ... `

Comment: And my response as follows below.. 
facet_fields":{
      "category_display_name":[
        "preCat_Dress Shoes",16,
        "preCat_Casual Tennis",9,
        "preCat_Casual Shoes",6,
        "preCat_Boots",5,
        "preCat_Accesories",1]},

Comment: So, you need to change <field name="category_display_name" type="text_ar" ... to <field name="category_display_name" type="text_en" ... 
Not text_en instead of that using type="string".. 
Thanks..

Comment: Check my edit to understand whay we should not use string as type in this case.

Comment: Hi nomade.. my schema.xml definition as looks below..
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
I still facing the splitting issue if i use text_en. So what tokenizer i should use to get the actual facets value?

Comment: Also I used  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/> as I came to know which will return actual value. But still it is returning below results on the 
Actual Results Indexed:preCat_Casual Shoes
Returned Results: preCat_Casual Sho
It just splices last two chracter.. Please let me know if you need more details..

Comment: Can you try adding this configuration `    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
     splitOnNumerics="0" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0"
     catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" />`

Comment: Hi if i add the above filter.. not returning facet results at all..
"facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{
      "true":0},
    "facet_fields":{
      "category_display_name":[]},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}}}

Answer (score 0):

When you're indexing into a textfield with a defined tokenizer (that isn't the KeywordTokenizer), the content is split into separate tokens based on certain rulesets. For the StandardTokenizer, this means that the content is split on whitespace and a few other special characters.

Since you want the complete value, you can use a TextField with a KeywordTokenizer (if you want to have a lowercasefilter as well to make case irrelevant), or if you want case to be significant, use a `string` field instead of a `TextField` with an analysis and tokenizer chain defined.